# Access Cloud Function via HTTP from ruby client, using google auth gem

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-auth-library, google-auth-library-ruby

I'm trying to use the ruby googleauth gem to authenticate a service account to make an HTTP call to a Cloud Function, without success.

Test code:

```rb
require 'googleauth'

class TestService
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  debug_output $stdout

  def test
    authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
      json_key_io: File.open(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']),
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
    options =
      {
        headers:
          {
            accept: 'application/json',
            authorization: "Bearer #{authorizer.fetch_access_token!['access_token']}"
          },
        query:
          {
            foo: 'bar'
          }
      }

    self.class.get('https://us-east1-xx-beta.cloudfunctions.net/my-cloud-function', options)
  end
end

TestService.new.test
```

(I am wondering if I should be specifying `audience` instead of `scope`, but I've been unable to make that work.)

I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var to be a path to a valid GCP service account key file, and have ensured that the service account in question *is* listed in the permissions for this Cloud Function with the Cloud Functions Invoker role.

Access fails with the following output.

```
opening connection to us-east1-xx-beta.cloudfunctions.net:443...
opened
starting SSL for us-east1-xx-beta.cloudfunctions.net:443...
SSL established, protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
<- "GET /my-cloud-function?foo=bar HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Bearer ya29.c.Kp8B-QfKOgrA5jwGxc3tK8MkX2RJqe0LcQqKtjo1hMDJawXJZWTOq3nZyOHkfHZMJpm5hbFr11T7LFTzbP4bnxX1SIUXJt-papBSKYU0lOKXXiqdwa9s5yN-oHD45qSp6bSOIMwzhG9GJC8ZqeOrbyJAhd5oqmZUgqDg_2cgGusA5wVViaJZtiBFC_TaMmBK06MUmGT2a1q4UGLIyH4nyug1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\r\nUser-Agent: Ruby\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: us-east1-xx-beta.cloudfunctions.net\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n"
-> "WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error=\"invalid_token\" error_description=\"The access token could not be verified\"\r\n"
-> "Date: Mon, 29 Mar 2021 19:42:21 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
-> "Server: Google Frontend\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 315\r\n"
-> "Alt-Svc: h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 315 bytes...
-> "\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/my-cloud-function?foo=bar</code>.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n"
read 315 bytes
Conn close
```

Comment: Cloud Functions require an OAuth Identity Token with the audience set to the function URL. You are sending an OAuth Access Token.

Comment: @JohnHanley that's what I suspected, but I haven't quite figured out how to get that right with the googleauth gem.  But thank for the nudge in that direction and I will pursue that.  And the function URL is the complete URL, correct? Including parameters?

Comment: Just the function URL, not the query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley mentioned, you are using access token as authorization on your function but you need an [Identity Token](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#identity_tokens) to successfully call the function. You can do that in your program by changing the `scope` to `target_audience`:

```
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']),
  target_audience: "GCF-TRIGGER-URL")
```

Then fetch the ID token using:

```
authorizer.fetch_access_token!["id_token"]
```

There's a clue in [`make_creds()`](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/googleauth/latest/Google/Auth/ServiceAccountCredentials.html) (view source) that specifying both scope and target_audience would raise an ArgumentError. Testing the library would show that specifying `scope` returns an access token while specifying `target_audience` would return an ID Token.